# Can these viruses be treated as false positives?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, clamav

Everytime I install **PlayOnLinux** with **wine**, and some of my GOG games **ClamAV** always finds viruses in the .PlayOnLinux directory. However, some of those viruses are in very peculiar places like Windows and Mono directories in the wine prefix.

I have always treated them as false positives, and would like some other opinions about this. Thank you.

```
$ clamscan --max-filesize=2000M --max-scansize=2000M --recursive=yes --infected /home
/home/alex/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Torchlight/drive_c/GOG Games/Torchlight/fmodex.dll: Win.Trojan.Ramnit-6905 FOUND
/home/alex/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Torchlight/drive_c/windows/Installer/4981.msi: Win.Trojan.Agent-1429193 FOUND
/home/alex/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Torchlight/drive_c/windows/mono/mono-2.0/bin/MonoPosixHelper-x86_64.dll: Win.Trojan.Agent-1429193 FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4867285
Engine version: 0.99.2
Scanned directories: 854
Scanned files: 3481
Infected files: 3
Data scanned: 5696.64 MB
Data read: 2768.52 MB (ratio 2.06:1)
Time: 613.390 sec (10 m 13 s)
```

[image: ClamAV Results]

Comment: If i am unsure about a certain file i usually upload it to https://www.virustotal.com/ - this quickly gives you a good impression how about 60 AV-scanners analyze it.

Comment: Yeah I have added the text directly, and virustotal returns that ClamAV is the only antivirus that finds viruses in these files.
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: The PUP detection in ClamAV (as well as in many others) is broken. For better results it's recommend to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run TWO anti virus programs to compare their results to determine if it is a bogus notice. Besides that: you also really need to search this notice yourself online.

I assume the answer is yes, these are bogus (as are 99.99999% of all of these notices):

- [Win.Trojan.Ramnit-6905 FOUND](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/2/487870763307588610/)
- [Win.Trojan.Agent-1429193](https://www.clamxav.com/BB/viewtopic.php?p=23594&sid=a2a546b7420de0340818618d82ae145d)
- [Win.Trojan.Agent-1429193](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833110)